# Receiving undefined on Controller layer using MSC model on a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, rest

I'm trying to make a sql query with a function using the MSC model, but i can't find the propper way to make it work. I can get the right error messages with the API but i cant create a new product.

i can't log my message, or receive an id (auto incremente on sql), how can i make this work?
Here is my code:

product.model

```
const regProduct = async (newProduct) => {
    const [sql] = await connection.execute(
      'INSERT INTO StoreManager.products (name) VALUES (?)',
      [newProduct],  
    
  );
  return { id: sql.insertId, name: newProduct };
};
```

product.service

```
const regProduct = async (name) => {
  const error = schema.validateName({ name });
  console.log(error.type, 'service error');

  if (error) return error;
  
  const newProduct = await productModel.regProduct(name);
  console.log(name);
  return { type: null, message: newProduct };
};
```

product.controller

```
const regProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  const { type, message, id, name: productName } = await productService.regProduct(name);
  
  console.log(message, 'controller message');

  if (type) return res.status(mapError(type)).json({ message });

  return res.status(201).json({ id, name: productName });
};
```

Thanks in advance for the time!

Answer (score 0):

on my product.service I forgot to get the type of my error
like this:

```js
const regProduct = async (name) => {
  const error = schema.validateName({ name });
  console.log(error.type, 'service error');

  if (error.type) return error;
  
  const newProduct = await productModel.regProduct(name);
  console.log(name);
  return { type: null, message: newProduct };
};
```

and on my product.controller I restructured my message like this:

```js
const regProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  const { type, message } = await productService.regProduct(name);
  
  if (type) return res.status(mapError(type)).json({ message });
  
  return res.status(201).json(message);
};
```